# Linux: Send raw usb packets in kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, kernel-module

I know that usb packets have a very specific format, but I would like to write those packets my self, I know that `usb_control_msg` is kind of an interface to control packets, but this function is already responsible from sending the setup_token, in/out token, and probably checks ACKS. How could I construct these packets myself and then sending them?

Comment: This problem must be solved, because USB passthrough to a VM works.  You should be able to do the same thing a VM does to control a real USB device from a virtual (userspace) process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like that what you want is to write your own usb host driver. I suggest you to try analyse existing usb host drivers (ehci/xhci) and then try to write your own driver, but be aware of this that this is not easy task to do. Notice also that it is not possible to exist more that one driver for given usb host controller (ehci/xhci). If you really want to do those things you need to know perfectly both: USB protocol and ehci/xhci specification which may take a lot of time. Also strong experience in writing Linux drivers is required. As I said it is not easy task.